# Enabling IntelliSense for Javascript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, emmet

For most of my languages like CSS and HTML, certain snippets will autofill which really helps me with my formatting and spelling since I'm not used to all the commands.

I've seen this work for Javascript in Youtube tutorials but even after installing every Javascript extension imaginable the autofill still will not work.

I've looked at the other related threads on this website but those don't seem to work for me either. Was hoping someone on here has had a similar problem.

My settings.json file

```
{
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Sapphire (Dim)",
    "css.styleSheets": [],
    "javascript.suggest.alwaysAllWords": true,
    "javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "enableTelemetry": false,
    "bracket-pair-colorizer-2.depreciation-notice": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
}
```

I tried implementing this code from online

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},`
```

but that did not work

Comment: give an example of code where you are triggering suggestions and where you are not getting the suggestions you expect to see.

Comment: snippets and intellisense are different things, emmet is a variation of snippets, be precise what you want to do